# Streamline multiple IF / ranges script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wondered if this script below:

```
function provaIf() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   if(spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue()  == 1){
   spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate(); }
   else {
   spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
   }
  }
```

you can streamline by making a shorter script. I write you an example below to help you understand what I have in mind:

```
if(A1=1;B1;C1)
```

I await your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as you have it's in the simplest way. The only change you could do, is to use a ternary operator [1] instead of an `if` statement, like this:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
(spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue()==1)?spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate():spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
```

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1):

```
function provaIf() {
  var dA=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:C1').getValues();
  return (dA[0][0]==1)?dA[0][1]:dA[0][2];
}
```

I hope you realize that you can't run this as a cell function since there are no inputs so it doesn't change when you change A1.  Unless you rerun the function.